# Fetching data from database using PHP

Tags: php, fetch, dta

I have tried to fetch data from priority table of elective_mgmt database.The source code is given below :

```
<?php
    $connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("elective_mgmt",$connect);
    $result = mysql_query($con,"SELECT * FROM priority");
        echo "<table border='1'>
`<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Roll</th>
<th>Email</th>
<th>Priorityone</th>
<th>Prioritytwo</th>
<th>Prioritythree</th>
</tr>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Roll'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Email']. "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Priorityone']."</td>";
  echo "<td" . $row['Prioritytwo']."</td>";
  echo "<td" . $row['Prioritythree']."</td>"; 
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysql_close($con);
?>

 ?>
```

When I run it ,it displays like this:

```
Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Elective_management\admin_view.php on line 5

Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Elective_management\admin_view.php on line 15
Name    Roll    Email   Priorityone Prioritytwo Prioritythree

Warning: mysql_close() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Elective_management\admin_view.php on line 28
?>
```

I didn't get any idea. Please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate [mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-select?answertab=votes#tab-top).

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11674313/250259) for how to troubleshoot this.

Answer (score 0):

you parameter order to `mysql_query` is incorrect. First the query then the connection.

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM priority", $connect);
```

Answer (score 0):

you have given wrong connection. Should looks like this

```
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM priority",$connect );
```

Answer (score 0):

you shouldnt need the connection variable since you just connected. You should be able to type

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM priority");
```

and have it work just fine

Answer (score 0):

### 1 -

```
mysql_close($con);
```

here you dont have a $con variable so its empty that why this error show up

```
Warning: mysql_close() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Elective_management\admin_view.php on line 28
```

Fix by :
Changing

```
mysql_close($con);
```

To

```
mysql_close($connect);
```

---

### 2 -

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result)`
```

here you point it to `$result` and in `$result` you have `$con = Null` so this error show up

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Elective_management\admin_view.php on line 15
```

Fix :

Will be fixed when you fix step three

---

### 3 -

```
$result = mysql_query($con,"SELECT * FROM priority");
```

here again you have the second parameter as a string and it shouldn't be a string so this error show up

```
Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Elective_management\admin_view.php on line 5
```

Fix :

Fix by :
Changing

```
mysql_query($con,"SELECT * FROM priority");
```

To

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM priority",$connect)
```

> **PS:** If you are just starting coding in this project
>   **Please Consider on changing your syntax from** MySql_* **to** PDO Syntax